# Can the line spacing or line height be changed?

Tags: kate

Is it possible to keep the font the same size and increase the space between lines of text?

I cannot find anything in the configuration settings or in the online handbook.

I'm getting old and have a hard time looking at the code without putting a blank line in between lines, but could get by if I could just increase the line spacing a bit.

If it matters, I'm using Manjaro and KDE.
Thank you.

Comment: I agree it would be nice to be able to adjust this.  If using Asian scripts (Chinese, Korean), the bottom of the glyph gets cut off on the standard setting.

Comment: @donnek In case you didn't see the new answer concerning the recent update to Kate that allows adjusting line spacing, it is now possible.

Comment: Cool - thanks for letting me know.  I'm on an older Ubuntu, so can't use the latest version, and unfortunately the AppImage doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Kate 22.12,<sup>1</sup> this feature now exists! See **Settings > Configure Kate > Appearance** for the Line Height Multiplier setting.

[image: Location of the line height multiplier setting in the Kate settings]

1. This is an upper bound on the version in which the feature was introduced. It may have been added earlier, but I could not find mention of it in a cursory search of the Gitlab issue tracker.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I forgot all about asking this, too, and am glad that SO informs the OP.

Comment: I gave up on using Kate a few years ago after failing to find the line height setting, Googling around, reading your question, and realizing it didn't exist made me move onto other editors. I recently learned that the feature was created, and I figured the least I could do is look this question up again and post an update :)

Comment: It was added in KTextEditor frameworks 5.93 about a year ago https://invent.kde.org/frameworks/ktexteditor/-/merge_requests/338. Which means that most probably Ubuntu LTS 22.04 will have this feature in its version of Kate

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can affect visible line spacing indirectly by choosing a font with different vertical arrangment. It's not a feature OP is looking for, but should be enough to *"just increase the line spacing a bit"*.

Answer (score 0):

I saved the text file in kate, opened it in LibreOffice, and then used the various "Format" options until the layout looked decent.